# How do I upload hundreds of digital camera photos to Facebook from Windows?

Tags: windows, images, photos, upload, facebook

I have hundreds of 5+ megapixel photos.  I would like a software which would batch-lower the resolution first to Facebook's dimension limits before upload, as well as "reject" images whose dimensions Facebook would reject anyway (what are they now?).

The app should also put images greater than 200 in to a separate album, since facebook has an image limit per album.

What tools can do this?

Comment: If you're looking for a desktop solution, the question will be fine to stay here, I guess. webapps.SE would focus on using the web app itself, not interacting with it through a desktop client.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**About 5+ megapixel limit:**

Use Image Resizer Powertoy Clone to resize them for Facebook. Make them 720x720 px. It's the simplest tool that you can find.

[Image Resizer Powertoy Clone](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phototoysclone/)

**About uploaders:**

[10 tools to upload photos to Facebook](http://www.allfacebook.com/upload-facebook-photos-tools-2010-08)

**UPDATE:**

Why 720x270 pixels:

1. It's the maximum display area of a photo at FB. You can upload bigger sizes, of course, but FB will resize them. I prefer to resize on my desktop instead of FB's resizer tools, the quality is not very good when FB resizes your photos.
2. To shorten your upload time.
3. You can resize what resolution you want too. 720 px. is just an advice. If you also want to keep high resolution files at FB, you can resize as 3000x3000, it will be smaller than 1MB and takes no time during uploading.

Comment: -1 -- 720x720 isn't the maximum resolution allowed by Facebook. it internally saves images that are larger than that. Also, linking to a website that offers other tools isn't encouraged on Super User. Please add some desktop tools *here* and explain how they work.

Comment: 720x720 is the maximum display area of a photo at FB. You can upload bigger sizes, of course, but FB will resize them.

Comment: Yes, it will resize them to be displayed, however if you click the "Download" link at a photo, you will be able to download it in its **original** size.

Answer (score 0):

For uploading, it'll be easy to use the copy-paste tool [clickto](http://www.clicktoapp.com).
Using that one will allow you, just to mark one or serveral pics, copy them and bring them to facebook with only 1 click.